# What does a Memory Device 1 A 4 yellow health status in Vmware mean?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm not exactly clear on what the above message means or how to troubleshoot it. My first instinct is a memory stick has errors / going bad and I need to run memtest to check this.  This would mean bringing down our main server so before I do this I'd like to hear from you guys if this is the correct path. At this point there has been no noticeable degradation of server performance.

Thanks for help in advance!

VMware ESXi Version 6.7.0 Update 3 (Build 16773714)

[[image: Hardware - Memory Device 1 A 4 Yellow Health1]
[image: Events - Memory Red]

Comment: If your platform has some kind of BMC management device, you should first look there for logs (IPMI SEL and alike) to see whether the hardware event was logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Short answer (from the basic information you gave)

Slot 1, bank A 4 RAM module seems to make trouble.

usually means that the cpu 1 rambank Slot A4 which can be directly found on the Mainboard need some maintenance or replacement

Comment: I can confirm now, Location A 4 contained the faulty module. Upon opening the server (PowerEdge) the memory banks were clearly labeled A1, A2, A3, etc... I replaced the memory and re-ran Dell's lifecycle controller hardware test. No more memory errors!

Comment: Thanks for the replay, i used dell for customer and had it for about 6 years on my support... :D